# Location of configuration for dashboard URL

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to log in to the Orchard Dashboard, but in the instance I'm working with, it has been configured so as to not show the log in link to the bottom, like the default theme does.

I've tried a bunch of URLs, including `OrchardLocal/Admin` and I get a 404. Is there a specific place to change the default URL for security purposes ?

I've tried looking in various XML files that have `DetailsRouteOrchard` nodes in them, but I have not found the URL for the dashboard.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe they changed this file: "...\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Dashboard\Routes.cs", this is the index action when you normally navigate to "/admin"

Comment: As a side note, "changing the default URL for security purposes" is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Project URL (like http://localhost:30321/OrchardLocal) in Web under Project properties and created new virtual directory.

[image: Image - Project Properties]

Source : [Orchard Dashboard is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303888/orchard-dashboard-is-missing/)