# Orchard Dashboard is missing

Tags: orchardcms

In my project Orchard Dashboard is missing

When I try to open any dashboard pages like http://localhost:30321/OrchardLocal/Admin, localhost:30321/OrchardLocal/Admin/Settings/Email etc are throwing one error message like

> The controller for path '/OrchardLocal/Admin/Settings/Email' was not found or does not implement IController.

[image]

Comment: Deleting the App_Data/Dependencies folder and rebuilding the whole solution has fixed this error for me in the past

Comment: Thanks @Xceno
Let me try..
If any problem after delete the Dependencies folder?

Comment: Sorry @Xceno it's not working for me...

Comment: If any other solution?

Comment: My website is working fine, only problem in dashboard

Comment: Check the logs to see what's really going on

Comment: I have checked that, but the log file is empty.

Comment: Try it without `OrchardLocal/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by changing the Project URL(http://localhost:30321/OrchardLocal) in Web under Project properties and created new virtual directory.

Now it's working fine

[Image - Project Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj9JK.png)